# Why am I getting an undefined return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

**EDIT:** Solved

I am building a website in wordpress and am currently editing a jquery plugin to return the clicked link's url in an alert box but it is returning undefined. This is only suppose to be trigger when clicking on one of the items in the navigation menu(which that part is working fine) see website link below for reference. Why is this happening?

snippet of code:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.start-pgm li', function() {
var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
alert(addressValue );
$.window({    title: "Cyclops Studio",    url: addressValue });
return false;
});
```

Additional information if it helps:

[Web Address I am working on](http://zackarylundquist.westhostsite.com/portfolio/)

[Jsfiddle with whole script](http://jsfiddle.net/zackarylundquist/v3A72/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shouldnt it be 

.on('click', '.start-pgm li a', function()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are registering a click listener on a `<li>` element which does not have a href attribute.

`.start-pgm li`